# Can't find the Cygdrive folder in Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, zsh

I installed cygwin, zsh and oh-my-zsh following this project:

https://github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/blob/master/README.md

And i can't find the cygdrive folder. Why? How can I mount my C:?

Answer (score 1):

You should automatically have a `/cygdrive` under a true Cygwin shell.  Drives will tend to appear and disappear from that directory automatically.  This is what I currently get when I do "ls -lF /cygdrive":

```
total 16
d---------+ 1 ???????? ???????? 0 Jul 23 19:14 c/
```

Comment: Interesting, but even if I "should", I don't

Comment: Is your shell a genuine cygwin shell?  What happens if you use the default cygwin icon to get a shell, does it show up there? Also, what do you see when you run the "mount" command without arguments?

Comment: It is genuine. I open it from C:\cygwin\cygwin.bat

Comment: Is it possible the location got modified in your cygwin `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: I don't have `/etc/fstab`, but I do have `/etc/fstab.d`, and it's empty

Comment: I took a closer look at that README, and that appears to be an unconventional way to install cygwin.  Usually you download the installer from the cygwin website and run it, and it sets up your system automatically for you.  (You also keep that installer because it's cygwin's "package manager".)

Comment: I found it, by doing `cd /c`. I will answer this question when I will be allowed to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason, it was in /c/ even though this folder is not visible if you do `ls` in the root